# Magento2 : how to reinstall magento setup?

Tags: magento2, sample-data, magento-installation

I am installing magento2 with sample-data. all requirement is completed and the Magento installation process starts but stops after some process.

I have to wait for the complete installation process but nothing happens. so I need to restart my magento2 set-up.

how it can be done? any have an idea for reinstall the Magento set-up without deleting the current code.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try the installation using the command line or did you use the web interface? What error did you see on screen or in the error logs? The causes of a failed installation are diverse. Could be a lack of missing one of the prerequisites - see https://github.com/magento/magento2 , could be too little memory, missing files. You need to narrow things down. Please add more information.

Comment: I am use web interface for installation and no error are displaying. file permision and system required is complete. it just displaying instling proess. how i can restart my magento setup ?

Comment: Post the relevant (php) error log results please. This will help us see what went wrong. Also check php.ini for amount of memory available and post here in your question.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to restart magento setup again from first step ?

Comment: magento previeos version for reinstall setup we do rename local.xml so what is for magento 2 for this prosess.

Answer (score 25):

Use the new Magento CLI -

**From the Magento Root Directory** `./bin/magento setup:uninstall`

**Note:** this will delete your database contents if you had one already set up.

Comment: what is the "."?  I added mage/bin to path but I get  'magento' is not recognized as an internal or external command, or if I use this code - '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: in your root magento "php bin/magento setup:uninstall"

Answer (score 17):

Magento 2 specific tip found [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1459):  Delete contents of `var/cache` and `var/generation` and try again. And it is probably also good to remove the `app/etc/config.php` and `app/etc/env.php` to do a fresh install according to comment made [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1460).

PS Always good to backup all before doing anything radical.

Comment: it is for magento previous version i need to do for magento2

Comment: got solution will inform it is work for me or not. rename app/etc/config.php and app/etc/env.php file.

Answer (score 13):

It was solved removing the `var/generation` folder. It is also important to remove the `app/etc/config.php` and `app/etc/env.php` to do a fresh install.

Comment: Great to here my suggested solution worked. Please select is as the solution and upvote it. Thanks. Actually there was no need to answer your answer this way as you only stated that the solution mentioned was working for you. A comment will do.

Comment: but i have find soltion before your suggestion. i have find solution by phpStorm local history functionality after i have try both file rename and restart my setup.

Comment: Ok. Sure.  Then an upvote would still be appreciated. I do think I made an effort to help you out. But it is up to you.